# Как можно сделать js код проще?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

В голове четкое понимание что этот код можно сделать более приятным для чтения и более удобным для дальнейшего редактирования.

Необходимо, чтобы при нажатии на "класс" остальные "классы" которые есть в списке исчезали. Может можно добавить атрибут к "input" чтобы при нажатии на него скрипт реагировал на него и делал его видимым?

```js
$('.go1').click(function() {
  $('.to1').css({
    'display': 'block'
  });
  $('.to2').css({
    'display': 'none'
  });
  $('.to3').css({
    'display': 'none'
  });
});

$('.go2').click(function() {
  $('.to2').css({
    'display': 'block'
  });
  $('.to1').css({
    'display': 'none'
  });
  $('.to3').css({
    'display': 'none'
  });
});

$('.go3').click(function() {
  $('.to3').css({
    'display': 'block'
  });
  $('.to1').css({
    'display': 'none'
  });
  $('.to2').css({
    'display': 'none'
  });
});
```

```css
.to1,
.to2,
.to3 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="btns1" name="radios" class="go1" value="">
<label for="btns1">go to1</label>

<input type="radio" id="btns2" name="radios" class="go2" value="">
<label for="btns2">go to2</label>

<input type="radio" id="btns3" name="radios" class="go3" value="">
<label for="btns3">go to3</label>

<div class="to1">to1
  <img src="">
</div>

<div class="to2">to2
  <img src="">
</div>

<div class="to3">to3
  <img src="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё что нужно это

1. обнулять у всех стиль
2. добавлять нужный к тому, что соответствует кликнутому

Можно сделать по-разному:

1. добавить соответствующие номера в виде дата атрибутов на парные элементы
2. можно опираться просто на индексы элементов (первый соответствует первому, второй - второму и т.д.)
3. можно парсить кликнутый класс - доставать оттуда индекс и сопоставлять такому же в нижнем блоке

```js
$(document).on('click', '.radio-btn', function() {
    $('.image-wrapper').css({ 'display': 'none' });
    let radioBtnId = $(this).data().radioId;
    $(`.image-wrapper[data-image-index="${radioBtnId}"]`).css({ 'display': 'block' });
    
    // Второй вариант:
    // $('.image-wrapper').eq(radioBtnId - 1).css({ 'display': 'block' });
});
```

```css
.to1, .to2, .to3 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="btns1" name="radios" class="go1 radio-btn" value="" data-radio-id="1">
<label for="btns1">go to1</label>

<input type="radio" id="btns2" name="radios" class="go2 radio-btn" value="" data-radio-id="2">
<label for="btns2">go to2</label>

<input type="radio" id="btns3" name="radios" class="go3 radio-btn" value="" data-radio-id="3">
<label for="btns3">go to3</label>

<div class="to1 image-wrapper" data-image-index="1">to1
<img src="">
</div>

<div class="to2 image-wrapper" data-image-index="2">to2
<img src="">
</div>

<div class="to3 image-wrapper" data-image-index="3">to3
<img src="">
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю! То что мне нужно.